# jQuery form validation before submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I currently have the following js that adds `error` class if the `required` fields aren't completed.

I need an if statement if any of the require fields are empty to not post the form.

Here is my JS at the moment.

```
function CheckPaymentForm(){    
    $('.required').removeClass('error').filter(function() {
        return !$.trim(this.value).length;
    }).addClass('FormError');

    var FormToSubmit = $( "#payment-form" ).serialize();    
    ProcessPayment(FormToSubmit);
};
```

I have tried various if statements on checking for the error class but without any joy.
I don't want to call the function `ProcessPayment` if I still have empty required fields.

Comment: If you want you can use required in html5 :) like: `<input type="text" required>`

Answer (score 0):

Change it to this...

```
function CheckPaymentForm(){    
    $('.required').removeClass('error').filter(function() {
        return !$.trim(this.value).length;
    }).addClass('FormError');

    // this will return before submitting, if there are any invalid inputs    
    if ($(".FormError").length) return;

    var FormToSubmit = $( "#payment-form" ).serialize();    
    ProcessPayment(FormToSubmit);
};
```

It simply checks for the class `FormError` that you add to invalid inputs.  If there are any then it drops out without sumbitting.

Also, I think you have an error in the code.  The `removeClass()` should probably remove `FormError` instead of `error`.

Comment: Looks perfect. Was too late for my head to come up with this :P Will try it out in the morning - thank you.